# How can i get the total count in if else condition loop in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I want to get the total count from the condition for loop, Let's say for the first row(I), the code will check through the if condition, if the condition meets the specific month then use the specific for loop to get the column count (for example : if the row's month is 1 then apply For k As Integer = 4 To dt.Columns.Count - 1 to get the count, if the row's month is 2 then apply For k As Integer = 4 To dt.Columns.Count - 2 to get the count and etc) follow by second row(I) and so on, after the if else condition k then return the total count ,how can i achieve it?

I have tried the method below but my code below did not work as what had been described above, it only return the count for the first condition,Please guide me on this :

```
For I As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
    'If dt.Rows(I).Item("Month").ToString = "1" Or dt.Rows(I).Item("Month").ToString = "3" Or dt.Rows(I).Item("Month").ToString = "5" Or dt.Rows(I).Item("Month").ToString = "7" Or dt.Rows(I).Item("Month").ToString = "8" Or dt.Rows(I).Item("Month").ToString = "10" Or dt.Rows(I).Item("Month").ToString = "12" Then
        For k As Integer = 4 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            If dt.Rows(I).Item(k).ToString() = "1" Then
                count1 += 1
            Else
                count1 = 0
            End If
               If count1 > 13 Then
                  Dx = True
                 End If
        Next k
    'ElseIf dt.Rows(I).Item("Month").ToString() = "2" Or dt.Rows(I).Item("Month").ToString() = "4" Or dt.Rows(I).Item("Month").ToString() = "6" Or dt.Rows(I).Item("Month").ToString() = "9" Or dt.Rows(I).Item("Month").ToString() = "11" Then
        'For k As Integer = 4 To dt.Columns.Count - 2
            'If dt.Rows(I).Item(k).ToString() = "1" Then
            '   count1 += 1
            'Else
            '   count1 = 0
            'End If
                           ' If total > 13 Then
                '  Dx = True
                  ' End If
        'Next k
    'End If


Next I
```

DataTable (column represents the date, month 11 has 30 columns and month 12 has 31 columns)

```
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Id  | year | month | 1  | 2  | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | till 31
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     kek | 2019 | 10     | 1  | 0  | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  0 | 0  |  0 |  1 | 
     kek | 2019 | 11     | 1  | 0  | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 | 1  |  1 |  1 | 
     kek | 2019 | 12     | 1  | 1  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  1 | 1  |  1 |  0 |
```

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3n3D.png)

Expected Output :

if the consecutive count from 11/11 till 12/12 is more than 13 then dx return true.

Comment: It is not clear what your different conditions are and what code you want to execute in each condition.

Comment: I have edited the question, sorry for didn't make the question clear enough.

Comment: Two comments: If the upper bound of the loop is the only difference, then store that in a variable and fill that variable from the two conditions. This will avoid a lot of duplicate code. If you simply want the sum of `count1` for all rows, then simply add a `total` variable and assign `total += count1` after the inner loop. Btw, it would also be nice if you could fix the formatting of your code.

Comment: What do you mean "Did not work as intended"? What happened? What did you get? What needs to change?

Comment: my code below did not work as what had been described above, it only return the count for the first condition but not for the both conditions.

Comment: You keep adding and then resetting. How do you think that will work? `count1 += 1` adds one, but then in the `else` you reset it to zero every time (`count1 = 0`). So your code says *add 1, then go back to zero, then add 1, then go back to zero*. That means you can count to 5 by hitting the first of each branch 5 times, and then the first time you hit either else you're at zero again. Does that sound like the way to count to a total? Grab a pencil and paper, and figure out how you'd do the math properly on paper. Once you have that figured out, you can write the code to implement that logic.

Comment: My intention is to get the latest consecutive day count for the specific month and the month before the specific month. For example i want to get the consecutive day count from month 11 to month 12, if the day count from month 11 to month 12 is more than 13 then dx will return true. eg: from 15/11/2019 to 15/12/2019 = 31days, it is more than 13 hence it returns true.

Comment: I understand that, but you're never going to get anything counted if you keep resetting the counter to zero in the counting loop. Do the math yourself. `i = 1; i += 1; means `i` becomes two. Adding another makes `i` equat three. Then `i = 0` makes `i` zero again, discarding the three you've already counted.  Learn to use the debugger. Stepping through the code would show you exactly where and how it's going wrong.

Comment: @Vanquisher - What if your `DataTable` contains 100 months - do you just want the last consecutive series of `"1"`s? Or do you want the consecutive count for the last `"1"` in each month by **counting backwards** even if it goes in to the previous month?

Comment: yes for this line -- > I want the consecutive count for the last "1" in each month by counting backwards even if it goes in to the previous month? i have this sql statement to catch the month that i checked on.  Dim sql As String = "Select * from LeaveSystem WHERE EmpID ='" + Session("empID") + "' and Year='" + Session("year") + "' and Month In(CONVERT(INT,'" + Session("month") + "')-1,'" + Session("month") + "')".

Comment: @Vanquisher - In that case it's really annoying that the data is in a `DataTable`. Can you just query as a big list of `DateTime, int` or as `int (year), int (month), int (value)`?

Comment: I have included the link for the screenshot, and reverted back the code, the code without if else works fine for the months that have 31 days, the if and else is to differentiate the months that don't have 31 days and get the consecutive count from there.

Comment: Could you not use the DataTable.Compute method?

Answer (score 0):

In your current code you're resetting `count1` to zero in each `Else`.

Also this code:

```
total += count1
If total > 13 Then
    Dx = True
End If
```

...looks like it should be outside the loop.

It seems to me that you need this:

```
For I As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim offset = 2
    If {"1", "3", "5", "7", "8", "10", "12"}.Contains(dt.Rows(I).Item("Month").ToString())
        offset = 1
    End If
    For k As Integer = 4 To dt.Columns.Count - offset
        If dt.Rows(I).Item(k).ToString() = "1" Then
            count1 += 1
        End If
    Next
Next
If count1 > 13 Then
    Dx = True
End If
```

If you want to get fancier then try LINQ:

```
Dim query = _
    From dr In dt.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow)()
    Let offset = If({"1", "3", "5", "7", "8", "10", "12"}.Contains(dr.Item("Month").ToString()), 0, 1)
    From k In Enumerable.Range(4, dt.Columns.Count - offset)
    Where dr.Item(k).ToString() = "1"
    Select 1

Dim total = query.Sum()

If total > 13 Then
    Dx = True
End If
```

Comment: Thanks,  My intention is to get the latest consecutive day count for the specific month and the month before the specific month. For example i want to get the consecutive day count from month 11 to month 12, if the day count from month 11 to month 12 is more than 13 then dx will return true. eg: from 15/11/2019 to 15/12/2019 = 31days, it is more than 13 hence it returns true and that's why the reset statement is there, month 11 has 30days so it will go through the else if statement and month 12 has 31days so it will go through the if statement Sorry for didn't present my question clear enough.

Comment: @Vanquisher - It's not clear at all - even with this explanation. What do you mean by "latest consecutive day count"?

Comment: @Vanquisher - Can you provide actual data for your `DataTable` and what you expect the result to be?

Comment: meaning to say the last consecutive day count in the loop.

Comment: @Vanquisher - What does "last consecutive day count in the loop" mean? You need to break this down even further sorry.

Comment: meaning to say the last consecutive count for column with value 1 that appear in the loop. the reset statement has done the tricks.